# ng-select dropdown ajax/object mapping

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Using angular ng-select, looking for the best practice/suggestion for linking the select drop-down with the selected option selected based on the properties of an object in scope.

1. The controller holds an object that (animal) that has a selected cat
2. The cats (options) are loaded from an Ajax call using any "promise" type angular service ($http in demo)
3. When the page loads, I want the selected cat to be the same as the animal.cat (would love to see easiest path to bi-directional mapping)

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/bMj7678djgPoJbiTRceG?p=preview

Service/Controller JS.

```
selectDemo = angular.module('selectDemo',[]);

selectDemo.factory("cat", ["$http", "$log", function($http, $log){
  return {
    query: function(runAfter){
      $log.debug("Getting cats from service");
      return $http.get('getCats.json');
    }
  }
}]);

selectDemo.controller('SelectDemoCtrl', ["$scope", "$log", "cat", function($scope, $log, Cat){
  $scope.animal = {type: "Mammal", cat: {"id": 2, "name": "Simon", "breed": "Persian"}};

  Cat.query().then(function(data){
    cats = data.data;
    $scope.cats = cats;
  });
}]);
```

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="selectDemo" ng-controller="SelectDemoCtrl">
    <h1>AngularJS Select Dropdown</h1>
    <div id="data"></div>
    <form role="form">
       <select data-ng-model="animal.cat" data-ng-options="cat.name for cat in cats">
          <option value="">Select a cat</option>
       </select>
    </form>
    <p>You selected: {{ animal.cat }}</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

JSON Response Object:

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "Garfield", "breed": "Tabby"},
{"id": 2, "name": "Simon", "breed": "Persian"},
{"id": 3, "name": "Twix", "breed": "Mixed"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/KTJt9602eD5Pgr1y7c9w?p=preview

The issue here is that the selected object from the `ng-options` needs to be *reference equal*  to the object referenced by `ng-model`, hence the need to find the object in the array.

Comment: This is very similar to my implementation, and I guess it doesn't "need" to be cleaner, but I wonder if there's a better practice for it, or anything that helps clean it up.  Thanks mate.